# What is the point of finding the best matching unit in a self organizing map?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

During the update step while training a self organizing map, the best matching unit for a particular input is found, then that BMU (and to a lesser degree it’s neighborhood) is perturbed to better match the input.

If we are using a Euclidian distance metric to find the neighborhood and update weights, is there a point to finding the best matching unit?
In other words, we can find distribution of units which match the input best by a Euclidean distance of all the units weights, and update the system accordingly, without the extra step of finding the BMU. Why isn’t that standard?

Answer (score 1):

The Best Matching Unit (BMU) in a Self-Organising Map (SOM), plays an important role in the training process, and its identification is not merely an extra step but rather a fundamental aspect of how SOMs learn and organise information. Here are some reasons why the BMU is important:

- **Focal Point for Learning and Adaptation:** The BMU is the neuron in the (SOM) whose weight vector is closest to the input vector, as measured by the Euclidean distance or another distance metric. It serves as a central point for adjusting the map to the current input. The BMU and its adjacent units on the map are modified to closely resemble the input vector, hence facilitating the representation of the input space's topological and metric relationships.
- **Topology Preservation:** One of the key features of SOMs is their ability to preserve the topological properties of the input space. By focusing on the BMU and its neighbours, the SOM ensures that similar input vectors are mapped to adjacent neurons in the map. The process of updating data specifically within the BMU aids in the creation of discrete zones on the map that correspond to various sorts of input data.
- **Efficiency:** As you stated, updating all units based on their distance to the input would take into account the distribution of all units. However, this strategy would be more computationally demanding and inefficient. The BMU-based strategy focuses learning in a localised region, making the self-organising process more computationally efficient and effective.
- **Control of Learning Rate:** The distance between a unit and the BMU can be used to adjust its learning rate. Units located closest to the BMU receive more frequent updates than those located further away. This smooth transition promotes smooth mapping by preventing abrupt changes in the map from upsetting the previously learned topological structure.
- **Convergence and Stability:** The map eventually stabilises over time by centering updates around the BMU. If all units were updated only on their Euclidean distance from the input, the learning could be less stable and more prone to fluctuations, making it more difficult for the map to converge to a stable solution.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but I am curious if you used GPT to write it?
After having done more research, the answer I'd write to myself is that:
A solution without the competitive selection of the BMU would mean that all neurons similar to the input would be perturbed towards the input, without any notion of where they are topographically. Because there can only be one BMU at each training step, we only update one neighborhood.